# Check if a csv file is comma or space separated and import it

Tags: r, dataframe

I have many files in a folder. Some of them are the comma separated CSV files while some are space separated CSV files. I wonder if I can check the type of a file and then import it into R for future use.

I know how to read the comma and space separated CSV files but do not know how to distinguish them first and then read them into R.

```
file_list<-list.files(pattern = "\\.csv")
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
   file<-read.csv(file_list[i],header = TRUE,sep = ",",fileEncoding = "utf-16")
}
```

I hope to have a result that can check the type of file and then import it into R. Something like the following:

if the file is comma-separated:

```
read.csv(file, sep = ",", fileEncoding = "utf-16")
```

else file is space-separated:

```
read.csv(file)
```

Maybe I need to explain my data more clearly. All my files are comma-separated values files. However, some of them are encoded as "UTF-16" while others are encoded as "UTF-8". Is there any method to read these two different types of files in the one-line code.

Comment: Try `data.table::fread` which, by default, tries to guess the separator.

Comment: When you say "space" separated, do you mean "tab" separated? Whatever the case, file names should reflect this, i.e. only comma separated should be CSV and only tab separated should be TSV.

Comment: @nicola I try to use fread to import the file but it tells me file is encoded in UTF-16 which is not supported. On the other hand, I can import the space-separated files using fread.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can check beforehand the separator of your csv. You could read them all with the separator you expect most of the times and if it fails do it the other way. If you have a separator, you expect more than 1 column. Thus, you could do

```
csvfile = read.csv(file,sep = ",", fileEncoding = "utf-16")

if (ncol(csvfile)==1){
   csvfile = read.csv(file,sep = " ", fileEncoding = "utf-16")
}
```